# Error-based SQL injection

Tags: sql-injection

I understand the conceptual idea behind error-based SQLi, but not the actual execution.

In particular, I can't make sense of this expression:

```
or 1 group by concat_ws(0x3a,version(),floor(rand(0)*2)) having min(0) or 1--
```

What's the reason for having "or 1", "floor(rand(0)*2)" and min(0)?

Comment: Do you know what the function "floor" does? Do you know that "or 1" is a common sqli snippet?

Comment: @schroeder I know what floor does. I've seen "or 1=1", "or '1'='1", but never "or 1".

Comment: I'm experimenting a bit [here](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_.._WHERE).
It seems that "or 1" is just "or true". I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error-based SQLi relies on a bug found in MySQL concerning the GROUP BY statement (see [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081) and [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60808)).

To trigger the bug one must follow the following rules:

1. Use an aggregate function.
2. GROUP BY a column that has two identical values on different rows.
3. The output of the rand() function must appear in the column of point 2 above.

The string

```
or 1 group by concat_ws(0x3a,version(),floor(rand(0)*2)) having min(0) or 1--
```

is injected in a WHERE clause, so `or 1` (which is equivalent to `or true`) is used to cancel out the previous conditions and display as many rows as possible. This way, there should be at least two rows with the same value for `floor(rand(0)*2))`. This takes care of points 2 and 3. We use floor() so that the values returned are just 0 or 1. If we were to use rand directly, it would be almost impossible to satisfy point 2.

We need `having min(0)` to take care of point 1.

Also, the instance of `or 1` at the end of the query is useless and can be removed.