# SQL Injection explain this query

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

```
' 1=1 GROUP BY CONCAT_WS ('~',version(), FLOOR(rand(0)*2)) having min(0)
```

1>> My first question is what is `CONCAT` function is being used for in this query

2>> And Why do we use having `min(0)` in here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is SQL injection?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: @tim - seems like he has a grasp of what SQL Injection is, but is trying to understand what specifically this attack is trying to do.  Doesn't seem like a duplicate to me.

Comment: The `CONCAT`, `rand`, and `min` look like attempts to (partially) disguise the attack string. Perhaps from some automated detection algorithm?

Comment: @AbeMiessler You are probably right. Normally, I'm careful what I flag, but here I might have jumped the gun a bit. The question also got improved a bit already, and I still think it could be improved further (what `CONCAT` does seems trivial, but eg why is there `FLOOR(rand(0)*2)` in addition to `having min` might be an interesting question).

Comment: I can't flag it as a duplicate again, but [Error-based SQL injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79569/error-based-sql-injection) is an exact duplicate of this question.

Comment: ok thank you Abe Miessler and neil smithline  and tim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, let's dissect it:

- [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) - Concatenate with separator.
- [`version()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_version) - Returns the version of MySQL.
- `FLOOR(rand(0)*2)` - Emits the following sequence of numbers: 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, ...
- `having min(0)` - By itself, this is illegal, as the `HAVING` clause requires a condition. This, and the fact that there's no `; --` on the end, implies that the injection is expecting a condition at the end.

So, this concatenates the version string and a sequence of numbers across a group. The sequence of numbers for the group clause is derived from `FLOOR(rand(0)*2)`.

The thing about `GROUP` is that it requires unique group keys. Since `version()` will return the same value each time, concatenating that and the output of `FLOOR(rand(0)*2)` three times will result in two different numbers (0, 1) then a second instance of 1, which causes an error (duplicate entry for group key), which is displayed back to the user. That error looks something like this:

> Duplicate entry '5.6.24-1~1' for key 'group_key'

This causes the version number to be leaked back in the response as part of an error-based SQL injection attack. This can then be expanded to perform other attacks.

As for *why* the attacker chose `FLOOR(rand(0)*2)`, it's a dead-simple expression which is reliable (the `rand()` function is a PRNG which takes a seed parameter; the same seed produces the same sequence always) and satisfies the requirement of having a duplicate output relatively quickly. You could pick a value other than 0 and it would still work.