# Help with Error-Based SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection

Like the guy in this thread :
[Error-based SQL injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79569/error-based-sql-injection)
I understand the idea behing SQL Error-Based Injection but not how it works on the MySQL server.

```
or 1 group by concat_ws(0x3a,version(),floor(rand(0)*2)) having min(0) or 1--
```

- Because we are on a WHERE clause, the `or 1` is here to cancel the previous condition and display many rows.
- `concat_ws()` is a function that take the first argument as separator and other arguments are the ones concatenate using the separator.
- `0x3a` is the hexadecimal for `:` - So colon is the separator
- `version()` kinda obvious, display the MySQL version
- `floor(rand(0)*2)` Round the result of `rand(0)*2` downward to its nearest integer

Now the big question is why this query display :

```
Duplicate entry '~'5.x.xx'~1' for key 1
```

And what is that having min(0) for ?

When I tried this using my computer :
`select concat_ws(0x3a,version(),floor(rand(0)*2))`
Result is just

```
5.6.24-0ubuntu2:0
```

So how the MySQL server interpret this query and how the duplicate things works ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be really nice if someone took time to hunt down the answer (Why `having min(0)` is resulting in a `Duplicate entry` error?) in the actual [source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server). Do anyone know where to start looking in the source code? I [started to look around](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Duplicate+entry+language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=Code) in the code but it is so massive so I have hard too find anything.